# JSON Object Tree console logged depending on depth [plane JS]

Tags: javascript, json, object

So I'm trying to get console.loged result similar to this:

```
LT 10
LT - Kaunas 2
LT - Kaunas - Centras 1
LT - Kaunas - Centras - lasives al. 0.5
LT - Kaunas - Žaliakalnis 1
LT - Vilnius 4
```

From this JSON object:

```
    var x = {
    "name": "LT",
    "size": 10,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "Kaunas",
            "size": 2,
            "nodes": [
                {
                "name": "Centras",
                "size": 1,
                "nodes": [
                        {
                        "name": "lasives al.",
                        "size": 0.5,
                        "nodes": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                "name": "Žaliakalnis",
                "size": 1,
                "nodes": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Vilnius",`enter code here`
            "size": 4,
            "nodes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My solution just iterates trough the object, but I can't figure out how to print everything depending on depth.

```
var name = [];

function Print(data) {
    for(var da in data) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(da) && typeof data[da] === 'object') {
            Print(data[da])
        } else {
            name.push(data[da]);
        }
    }
}

Print(x);
```

Tried it seems everything, I think it should be close to one line of code, but can't figure it out. Lack of knowledge it seems :)

Comment: There's no JSON in the question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Good to know :) But I think everyone here understands that this object isn't JSON, just similar structure.

Comment: The point is: Why say it's JSON when it's not? Just say it's an object tree. That's what it is. Even if the starting point *were* JSON, the first thing you'd do is parse it, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a recursive function that accepts a prefix string, see comments:

```
function render(obj, prefix = "") {
    // Show this object's information
    console.log(prefix + obj.name + " " + obj.size);
    // Add its name to the prefix
    prefix += obj.name + " - ";
    // Recurse for each of its nodes
    for (const node of obj.nodes) {
        render(node, prefix);
    }
}
render(x);
```

```js
var x = {
    "name": "LT",
    "size": 10,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "Kaunas",
            "size": 2,
            "nodes": [
                {
                "name": "Centras",
                "size": 1,
                "nodes": [
                        {
                        "name": "lasives al.",
                        "size": 0.5,
                        "nodes": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                "name": "Žaliakalnis",
                "size": 1,
                "nodes": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Vilnius",
            "size": 4,
            "nodes": []
        }
    ]
};

function render(obj, prefix = "") {
    // Show this object's information
    console.log(prefix + obj.name + " " + obj.size);
    // Add its name to the prefix
    prefix += obj.name + " - ";
    // Recurse for each of its nodes
    for (const node of obj.nodes) {
        render(node, prefix);
    }
}
render(x);
```

That uses some ES2015+ features, but the ES5 version is quite similar:

```
function render(obj, prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || "";
    console.log(prefix + obj.name + " " + obj.size);
    prefix += obj.name + " - ";
    obj.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
        render(node, prefix);
    });
}
render(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array as data and use a closure over the path.

```js
var data = { name: "LT", size: 10, nodes: [{ name: "Kaunas", size: 2, nodes: [{ name: "Centras", size: 1, nodes: [{ name: "lasives al.", size: 0.5, nodes: [] }] }, { name: "Žaliakalnis", size: 1, nodes: [] }] }, { name: "Vilnius", size: 4, nodes: [] }] };

[data].forEach(function iter(path) {
    return function ({ name, size, nodes }) {
        console.log(path.concat([name, size].join(' ')).join(' - '));
        nodes.forEach(iter(path.concat(name)));
    };
}([]));
```